# can not find content folder in prestrashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am new in prestrashop. I am working on http://www.how2brich.com 
website. There is about menu. I have putted  content of this menu through admin but i want to change some data inside the code.

the link is showing http://how2brich.com/content/4-about-us this.

I am not content folder and 4-about-us page for change code.

Any one plz help where to get about-us page content.

Comment: [You can edit these at Tools>CMS](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/141564-changing-terms-legal-notice-about-us/).

Answer (score 1):

To change content of this page go to Preferences >> CMS and if you want to change the code go to `"/themes/yourthemename/cms.tpl"` but keep in mind it will change all CMS pages code so add a condition(like if , else) to add specific code for this page.

Answer (score 0):

To get content editor "about-us" page please enter Back-Office. Then Preferences->CMS. And then please click on button "edit" on the "about-us" line.
If you need to change the code (template) of the cms pages please find the template on the path "themes/your_theme/cms.tpl"